# I want the update is only done once for the modified object

Tags: python, odoo

I have this method and when I modify one record then all records are changed, I want to only do the "update" of the modifyed but not of all others

```
    @api.multi
    def _calculate_geom(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.cor != False:
                self.env.cr.execute('SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(\'MULTIPOLYGON((('+str(record.cor).encode('utf-8')+')))\',4326),900913)')
                record.cor2=record.env.cr.fetchone()[0]
                if record.cor2 != False:
                    self.env.cr.execute('UPDATE '+self._name.replace('.', '_')+' set the_geom=\''+record.cor2+'\'')
```

Comment: When does this function run?

Comment: `cor2 = fields.Char('Geom Translate',compute='_calculate_geom')`
`the_geom = geo_fields.GeoMultiPolygon('NPA Shape')`

Comment: Then the function will run every time you enter a view of this object for all the objects, not when you modifuy one. Maybe a function field isnt what you need, you may try to re-define the write function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An UPDATE will affect all rows unless a WHERE clause is specified.
To affect only the intended row you need to add a `WHERE id=%d'.
Also, you should not build SQL using concatenation, it has a risk.

Something like:

```
sql = "UPDATE %s SET the_geom=%s WHERE id=%d"
self.env.cr.execute(sql, self._tablename, record.cor2, record.id)
```

Unless I'm missing something, if I were you I would just do:

```
record.the_geom = record.cor2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't misunderstand your question, you just need to add a `break` statement after the update query, so the `for` loop exit after the first time that  query is executed.

Comment: It is Odoo by which changes each time you create or then modified in this way does not work